# NoSuchDriverException executing Selenium in AWS Lambda from Image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

After looking all over the internet I concluded that I need help. Im trying to deploy a Python script on AWS Lambda. All was going good, but at the moment to test the function in AWS, it throws and error.

Previously I have tested the app locally using sam local invoke and its working correctly.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 as stage
# Hack to install chromium dependencies
RUN yum install -y -q sudo unzip
# Find the version of latest stable build of chromium from below
# https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/
# Then follow the instructions here in below URL 
# to download old builds of Chrome/Chromium that are stable
# Current stable version of Chromium
ENV CHROMIUM_VERSION=1002910 
# Install Chromium
COPY install-browser.sh /tmp/
RUN /usr/bin/bash /tmp/install-browser.sh
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 as base
COPY chrome-deps.txt /tmp/
RUN yum install -y $(cat /tmp/chrome-deps.txt)
# Install Python dependencies for function
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip -q
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt -q 
COPY --from=stage /opt/chrome /opt/chrome
COPY --from=stage /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

My Script snippet:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import bs4, requests

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

The error log:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location\n",
  "errorType": "NoSuchDriverException",
  "requestId": "847fc34f-5bfc-4d7f-b58c-b92ae3a6c857",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 36, in handler\n    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 45, in __init__\n    super().__init__(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py\", line 51, in __init__\n    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py\", line 41, in get_path\n    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err\n"
  ]
}
```

I've tried to download Selenium 4.6 in the dockerfile but i cant pass sam local invoke due to the following error:

```
START RequestId: c5e79a40-fd10-483f-84bd-ac83c7191d3d Version: $LATEST
/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ERROR] WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

supposedly with 4.6 i dont need to have the executable so i dont understand this error and the library libssl, it needs to be added to the dockerfile?

Thanks in advance